# How can I use the fact that I figured out the derivative of $f(x)=x^x$ for $f_2(x)=x^{x^x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> How can I use the fact that I figured out the derivative of $f(x)=x^x$
>   for $f_2(x)=x^{x^x}$?

So, I showed that $f'(x)=x^x(\ln(x)+1)$. Could I somehow use this knowledge for $f_2$?

Comment: $f_2(x) = x^{f(x)}$, use chain rule

Comment: $f(x)^x$ would also be possible?

Comment: No, $f(x)^x = x^{x^2}$, a different function. Look at the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Write $y=x^x$ then $z = x^y$ so $$\ln z = y\ln x$$ implies $${z'\over z} = y'\ln x+{y\over x}$$

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of, but it doesn't solve the whole problem. $x^{x^x} =e^{x^x\ln x} $, so you can use the chain rule to get
$$x^{x^x} \frac d{dx} (x^x\ln x) $$
Then use the product rule and the derivative of $x^x$ comes up.